# Why does this GCD operation result in deadlock?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, asihttprequest, grand-central-dispatch

I know that deadlock ensues if you call a `sync` dispatch from another `sync` dispatch on the same serial queue, but that is the only "known" cause of GCD deadlocks I've heard of.

I am using a global concurrent queue, so I'd expect `sync` requests to not lead to deadlock. I have this code, which is using `ASIHTTPRequest`:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

[self.networkQueue cancelAllOperations];

self.networkQueue=nil;

self.networkQueue=[ASINetworkQueue queue];
});
```

The idea was to try to speed up the `cancelAllOperations` part, since that can take quite a long time if you have a couple thousands operations in the `networkQueue`.

But when I call this code, deadlock ensues. If I take this block out of GCD and run it on the main thread, there is a delay while `cancelAllOperations` runs, but it does complete without deadlock. When inside this dispatch, however, the app freezes and iOS eventually terminates the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this slightly wrong.

Using `dispatch_sync()` to enqueue a Block to the serial queue on which you're already running is guaranteed to deadlock.

Using `dispatch_sync()` to enqueue a Block to the *concurrent* queue on which you're already running is *quite likely* to deadlock. You're relying on the queue almost immediately dequeueing the synchronous block, which may or may not happen depending on available resources.

You also seem to be misunderstanding the nature of the concurrency offered by the queue. Submitting `[self.networkQueue cancelAllOperations];` to a concurrent queue is not going to speed it up -- that method call isn't sliced into various units of work on the queue. Instead, the entire Block that you've submitted -- all three lines there -- is one unit for the queue. It may run concurrently with other Blocks that you submit, but it cannot *itself* take advantage of any concurrency. You would have to split the work up yourself and submit each unit as a separate Block -- sending `cancel` to each operation on the `NSOperationQueue`, for example.

You should most likely be using `dispatch_async()` for this.

Comment: the idea is that this block as a whole might run faster if submitted to a concurrent queue than on the main thread, but it is a `sync` operation because I cannot proceed until the block finishes. but now I understand that a `sync` operation to a concurrent queue is a bad idea.

Comment: If you have to wait for it, you have to wait for it. Dispatch queues don't make things go faster, they just (when used asynchronously) allow them to happen "at the same time" as other things -- so you don't _have_ to wait. The only way to speed this up would be to break it down, submit each piece to a concurrent queue, and wait on the whole thing.